# Detect iPhone 24-Hour time setting

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

I'm using a UIDatePicker to select a time. I am also customising the background of the picker, however I need 2 different images depending on whether the user is using 12 hour mode (which displays AM/PM column) or 24 hour mode.
How can I detect the users setting for the 12/24 hour time?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972108/detect-whether-iphone-is-displaying-time-in-12-hour-or-24-hour-mode)
- [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033099/how-detect-time-settings-of-device)
- [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448360/detect-if-time-format-is-in-12hr-or-24hr-format)

and there's probably many, many more...

Comment: Wow, thanks. I did a Google search which normally shows Stack Overflow results but I came up completely blank!

Answer (score 39):

Even shorter than the others:

```
NSString *format = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"j" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
BOOL is24Hour = ([format rangeOfString:@"a"].location == NSNotFound);
```

## Explanation

The string formatting character to represent the am/pm symbol is "a", as documented in [Unicode Locale Markup Language – Part 4: Dates](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

The same document also explains the special template symbol "j":

> This is a special-purpose symbol. It must not occur in pattern or skeleton data. Instead, it is reserved for use in skeletons passed to APIs doing flexible date pattern generation. In such a context, it requests the preferred hour format for the locale (h, H, K, or k), as determined by whether h, H, K, or k is used in the standard short time format for the locale. In the implementation of such an API, 'j' must be replaced by h, H, K, or k before beginning a match against availableFormats data. Note that use of 'j' in a skeleton passed to an API is the only way to have a skeleton request a locale's preferred time cycle type (12-hour or 24-hour).

The `NSString` method `dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:` is described in Apple's [`NSDateFormatter` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDateFormatter/dateFormatFromTemplate%3aoptions%3alocale%3a):

> Returns a localized date format string representing the given date format components arranged appropriately for the specified locale.

So, what that method will do is turn the `@"j"` you pass in as a template in to a format string suitable for `NSDateFormatter`. If this string contains the am / pm symbol `@"a"` in it anywhere, then you know the locale (and other user settings being interrogated by the OS for you) wants am / pm to be displayed.

Comment: I was totally about to down vote your answer as not working, until I read it a lot closer. That's clever. Nice one!

Comment: Just to add that this will not work on the simulator.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe this will work in 10.14 unless your application is localized in the user’s language.  The system now does what iOS does and returns currentLocale only in a language that your app is localized in, which will not actually match the user locale.

Comment: @PeterNLewis Do you know that it is not working? Or is that just a guess? I do not have an Apple Developer Account and can not test it on my iPhone

Comment: Yes, I know it does not work. NSDateFormatter  will use the users locale in formatting dates, and so the result may not be "am/pm" depending on the language and the user locale settings.

Answer (score 7):

Swift (3.x) version of two most popular solutions in form of Date extension :

```
extension Date {

    static var is24HoursFormat_1 : Bool  {
        let dateString = Date.localFormatter.string(from: Date())

        if dateString.contains(Date.localFormatter.amSymbol) || dateString.contains(Date.localFormatter.pmSymbol) {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    static var is24HoursFormat_2 : Bool {
        let format = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "j", options: 0, locale: Locale.autoupdatingCurrent)
        return !format!.contains("a")
    }

    private static let localFormatter : DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()

        formatter.locale    = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        formatter.dateStyle = .none

        return formatter
    }()
}
```

Usage :

```
Date.is24HoursFormat_1
Date.is24HoursFormat_2
```

Swift (2.0) version of two most popular solutions in form of NSDate extension :

```
extension NSDate {

    class var is24HoursFormat_1 : Bool  {
        let dateString = NSDate.localFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

        if dateString.containsString(NSDate.localFormatter.AMSymbol) || dateString.containsString(NSDate.localFormatter.PMSymbol) {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    class var is24HoursFormat_2 : Bool {
        let format = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("j", options: 0, locale: NSLocale.autoupdatingCurrentLocale())
        return !format!.containsString("a")
    }

    private static let localFormatter : NSDateFormatter = {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()

        formatter.locale    = NSLocale.autoupdatingCurrentLocale()
        formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
        formatter.dateStyle = .NoStyle

        return formatter
    }()
}
```

Please note that Apple says following on NSDateFormatter ([Date Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW10)) :

> Creating a date formatter is not a cheap operation. If you are likely
>   to use a formatter frequently, it is typically more efficient to cache
>   a single instance than to create and dispose of multiple instances.
>   One approach is to use a static variable.

Thats the reason for static let

Secondly you should use NSLocale.autoupdatingCurrentLocale() ( for is24HoursFormat_1 ), that way you will always get the actual current state.