# How to determine programmatically if current locale uses AM/PM or 24h format for time?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nslocale

I have a 24h formatted time string like 13:30 which I must translate into a 12h time format string when the user's locale uses AM/PM. How can I detect that reliably?

Comment: It's not just the locale. Regardless of locale, the user can choose to use 24-hour time (or not) in the Settings app under General, Date & Time.

Comment: Have you tried [NSLocale currentLocale] or [NSLocale systemLocale] ?

Comment: @rmaddy is correct.  You can get bit if the locale is one way and the Settings value is the other way, and I'm not sure there's a good way to test for this other than to format something and see how it turns out.  Note that the Settings value even overrides explicit "hh"/"HH" notation in a NSDateFormat format string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few methods. See my question here [Detect iPhone 24-Hour time setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214398/detect-iphone-24-hour-time-setting)
Basically you set a time and check the string for am or pm